# Bootstrap/CSS Newbie: Dropdown not opening when clicked on (CDN should be installed correctly)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

As title suggested, I cannot seem to get my Bootstrap dropdown to toggle correctly. Checked the other supports and it was suggested that CDN was not imported correctly. However, in my script, the JS is placed last. What may I be doing wrong? Tried with different browsers as well. Thanks for your help!

```css
.Jumbotron {
  background-color: rgb(211, 211, 211);
  padding: 50px;
}

.my_modal {
  margin: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  border-color: green;
}

.my_modal:hover {
  background-color: darkgreen;
  border-color: darkgreen;
}

.my_modal:onclick {
  border-color: darkgreen;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Need this to run bootstrap that runs using CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Add style.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- Add A Navbar taken from Bootstrap -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
          aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li>
                  <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                </li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="d-flex">
            <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Add Jumbotron from Bootstrap -->
    <div class="Jumbotron">
      <h1 class="display-3">Hello World!</h1>
      <p class="lead">This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component
        for calling extra attention to featured content or information.</p>
      <hr class="my-4">
      <p>It uses utility classes for typography and spacing to space content out within
        the larger container.
      </p>
      <p class="lead">
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">
          Learn more</a>
      </p>
    </div>

    <!-- Add Modal from Bootstrap  -->
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary my_modal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
      Launch demo modal
    </button>
    
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            ...
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Need this to run bootstrap that runs using JS (lower priority than CSS) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are importing Bootstrap 4, however you are using the Bootstrap 5 dropdown.

You need to replace:

`data-bs-toggle="dropdown"`

With:

`data-toggle="dropdown"`

So, you will finally have:

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
          aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
```

Bootstrap 4 Docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/dropdowns